# Decrypt or deobfuscated SQL Server 2000 exported script exec(decrypt(0x02B4

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have a very very old customer who bought a program developed in vb5 and SQL Server 7. The last time they hired me was just to migrate the very old server where SQL Server was running into a VM. The new software I sell doesn't have the same objective, so I can't sell the software again. And that version disappeared in the time.

Nevertheless, the program survived all this time in his VM, but now the renew servers and migrate the VMs to a new computer. In the VM migration the Virtual Machine was corrupted. They had the Data backup (just tables)... and everything could be rebuild from a very old script I had from that customer.

In the script I have three times the same deprecated command for restore 3 different scripts.

I don't have SQL Server 2000 any more (the latest certified structure where I took this script) and if I try to implement it in any new version the word "decrypt" do not exists any more.

Can you help me to convert from the following to plain text?, better if it is in a native T-SQL

```
exec(decrypt(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
))
```

Comment: clarification: The program is my intellectual property. I don't have in my source control the oldest scripts. The customer who bougth the program want to recertify the code to SQL 2018 at least. There is software out there to decrypt the stored procedures that are published into a database. In this case those 4 spcripts were made with encryption what I know is a obfuscation technic.

Comment: If you're asking how to decrypt something without the key, you are out of luck.

Comment: There are several software (free and commercial) that currently Decrypts or deobfuscates the stored procedures IF are deployed into the database.  In SQL 2000 you was able to run the command in T-SQL " Exec(Decrypt(<hexa value to decrypt>)) " and you could reimplement the encrypted code into the database... Currently I am trying to mount a MSDE in windows 10 without any good result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking us to decrypt information he allegedly previously encrypted and is no longer able to decrypt.

Comment: Thank Alex, I did several years ago... I learn to have better process to  have secure the code. Best practices were implemented.  But I can't change the past.

Comment: Alex I am voting for give some help... Like... right now I am trying to install MSDE to run scripts and everything will be ok. Sadly it does not work with the current versions of windows that I have available right now. Remember that teh "SQL Encryption" in SQL 7 and 2000 is not a real encryption, was a obfuscation.  If anyone knows if the T-SQL word "decrypt" is accepted in earlier versions of SQL please let me know.  I will appreciat all your help.

Comment: A true blast from the past. It appears the `ENCRYPT`/`DECRYPT` functions were never documented, not even in the versions that supported them (certainly not SQL Server 2000 -- I have no documentation that goes back further than that). Nobody seems to have ever taken the bother to reverse the algorithm. Given sufficient time and effort it can probably be reversed from the implementation, but just using a VM is certainly not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download MSDEa sp4
2. Use or install VirtualBox or VMWare
3. Download XP virtual disk and create Virtual Machine (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-windows-xp-for-free-and-legally-straight-from-microsoft-si/)
   If you already have VMWare may be you need to see
   http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-migrate-vhd-to-vmware-workstation.html
4. Install MSDEa sp4 in the XP virtual Machine
   setup SAPWD=hello INSTANCENAME="InstanceName" TARGETDIR="C:\MyInstanceFolder"
5. Start server
   *Run CMD 
   *locate the instance directory
   c:\MyInstancefolder$InstanceName\Binn\Sqlservr
6. Go into the sql command line editor
   osql -E
7. Create a new Database (change mynewdatabase by the name you like for it)
   create database mynewdatabase
   go
   use mynewdatabase
   go
8. Execute the command decrypt including the hexadecimal value 
   exec(decrypt(0x0******   ...  ****))
   go
9. Open a new cmd window and create a sql file following the text I found in

   http://sqlserver2000vl.blogspot.com/2012/01/decrypt-sql-server-2000-stored.html. 
   I will say that the file is called myfile.sql
10. Execute the script (change yourdatabase by the name of the database you create)

    `osql -E -dyourdatabase -imysqlfile.sql`
    (if it looks like halted, just press couple times cntrl+break, but only if it take several minutes)
11. now you can use

`osql -E -dyourdatabase -q"sp_helptext yourspname" > yourspname.sql`

11. press ctrl+break to finish the export process.

there could be a better and faster process, but with this you can solve the issue.